# Where is the Tab Order Assignment dialog in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tab-ordering

For as long as I can recall, Visual Studio has had an integrate dialog that allows you to easily organize the tab order of your controls.

I've just created my first VS 2012 WinForms project, added all of my controls and went to find the Tab Indexing dialog, and it appears to be missing from Visual Studio.

I found [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csz6b8x8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which states that I can open this dialog by going to FORMAT>Tab order.  The problem is that there is no Tab Order option on my FORMAT menu.  Alternatively, the documentation states th at Ctrl+D should open this dialog.  It doesn't.

Another alternative is to select the VIEW>Tab Order menu option.  This method causes Tab Index boxes to hover over your controls.  You can subsequently click on your controls, one at a time, in the order in which you want them to tab, to set the tab order.

This isn't acceptable because my form contains numerous panels and group boxes that cover one another.  It is impossible for me to click-through my controls because many of them are no longer visible in the designer.

Is there an easy way for me to setup the tab order of my controls like there previously use to be within older versions of Visual Studio?

Comment: you can try this addon. Disclaimer - I'm the suthor of this addon. http://codecanyon.net/item/winforms-tab-index-addin/4567358?WT.ac=category_thumb&WT.seg_1=category_thumb&WT.z_author=Rifky

Comment: You're not crazy, RLH: there is a "Tab Order" dialog in Access which works that way for form design.

Comment: Aaaaaah... Thank you!  I knew I've seen one, somewhere.  I use to do a lot of work maintaining old VBA code (actually in Excel.)  I bet that's where I remember it.

Comment: The documentation for Visual Studio 2015 says Format Menu. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csz6b8x8.aspx.  Mine is on the View menu nevertheless.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It is still available, you just need to add it back to the View menu.  Tools + Customize, Commands tab, Menu bar = View.  Select the menu item in Controls where you want to insert it, say the bottom one.  Then Add Command, Category = View, Commands = Tab Order.

[image: Tab Order]

Your memory of this command does sound a bit hazy, it was never on the Format menu and its never been a dialog.  If you want to put it on the Format menu then you can, just pick the Format menu bar in the Commands tab.  You can't make it a dialog though, it numbers the controls in the designer view.  Some odds that you actually remembered the View + Document Outline command.

Comment: Hans Passant: This did add the option back into my menu.  The variant that I need was available within the "Format" category of your last step and not the one under the View category.  However, when I added this menu option, it is disabled on the menu.  Is there some reason why I can't get this feature to work?  I've clicked on the form in the designer, I've clicked on a modifiable control.  Nothing seems to change the state of the Tab Order menu option that should open this dialog.  Any idea?

Comment: The Tab Order command is disabled until the designer has at least one control to work with.  Are you sure that you remember the correct command, you keep talking about a dialog?  It has never been a dialog.

Comment: It's been a long time since I had to use such a tool but I thought there was (years ago, possibly in Visual Basic 6) a dialog that allowed you to move your controls up and down on a form.  The order they were set, was the order they would tab.  I guess I'm wrong.  This could have been a plug-in that I'm thinking of.  In fact, I use to use Infragistics tools.  Maybe it was part of their plug-ins and that's what I'm thinking of.

Comment: Right, you are completely mixing things up.  View + Document Outline is available to easily change the Z-order of controls.  Z-order used to set the tab order in olden GUI tools like VB6 and the C++ IDE's dialog designer.  But not in Winforms, the tab order is determined by the TabIndex property of a control.  Directly available in the Properties window, the Tab Order command is a tool to help set that.

Comment: Yes, I did not see the 'Tab Order' selection until I actually selected the form.  The 'Tab Order' selection was than available under the View menu

Answer (score 47):

Go to your alignment toolbar.  At the end, click the tiny little "Add or Remove Buttons" down arrow.  Click the "Add or Remove Buttons" button, and look towards the bottom of the list.  You should see Tab Order.  Click on that and it will be added to the alignment toolbar.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found this to be very useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csz6b8x8.aspx

It allows you to simply click on the various controls in the order that you want them to tab through.  You do this while you are in the "Show tab order" mode as described above; the tip from Elton about adding the icon to a toolbar makes it easy to toggle the mode.

Ctrl-doubleclick the first control, then click subsequent controls, and press Enter to terminate.  You can also start on the Nth control if you Ctrl-click the one before it, then click in order as normal.

(VS Express 2013)

Answer (score 3):

The Tab order tool from the view menu disappears in some cases. For example, if you clikc a text box, then go to its properties, the tab order option will not show. You must select a control, then immediately go to the view menu and choose tab order.

Answer (score 0):

You can click through your controls with the Document Outline view. If they all have the same TabIndex value, their Z-order will be used as tab order. The Z-order can be changed also with the Document Outline view.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't click through the tab order. I have controls, stacked on top of controls-- I can't see all of the tab-numbering boxes because of this.

Comment: @RLH The Document Outline view is a Tree control listing all controls, organized by their containers. You can click through them all in the Document Outline which causes them to become selected in the Designer View.

Comment: You write "The Z-order can be changed also with the Document Outline view." Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but how? When I select a control, then, yes, it is selected in the design window, but it's still hidden behind other controls. The right-click menu has no "Bring to front" or "Send to back" entries. I can click on the four-headed arrow on the design window and select "Bring to front" - is that maybe what you mean? Or is there something more intuitive that my intuition is missing?

Comment: @RenniePet You can drag items in the document view to different positions and even re-parent them--again by dragging.