# How to set the tab order / TabIndex when you have multiple stacked panels?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, design-time

There's already one thread here about this, but no real conclusion was ever arrived at for the problem of stacked panels. [Where is the Tab Order Assignment dialog in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419007/where-is-the-tab-order-assignment-dialog-in-visual-studio-2012)

Here's what Visual Studio designer looks like when I select View - Tab Order:

[image]

There are 8 panels stacked on top of each other. At design time they are all marked Visible = False. At runtime one is marked Visible = True, according to the user's selection in the left panel. (These are Developer Express controls, by the way.)

Is there something I'm missing, or is it not possible to set tab order in this way?

Comment: Well, that got out of hand pretty badly.  Code probably isn't very pretty either.  If you need a structural fix then switch to UserControls.  If you need a quick fix then [use a TabControl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2798241/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for your comment. I assume your suggestion of using UserControls implies I should create 8 separate source files and classes, one for each panel? If so I think that would be overkill for this particular job.

Comment: Well, I anticipated this so gave you the quick fix.

Comment: @HansPassant: I have done what you suggest regarding switching to using a TabControl, except that I'm using a DevExpress XtraTabControl. It doesn't even need the WndProc method, as it has an option for turning off the tab headers. So at design time I have the tab headers visible, which is a great convenience (no more finding the control and "bring to front"), and at runtime turned off. Please make this suggestion into an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again.