# How can the tab index on a WinForms app be reset?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019, tabindex

I have a single page WinForms app with dozens of 'tab-able' labels, textboxes, sliders, combo-boxes and other controls.

This is my first real app so the tab index is out of control. I want to reset it and essentially start over.

There are many items that I don't even want tab-able (such as labels).

I know this can be done manually, but I assume there must be a way to batch process this change besides creating code during initialization to modify the tab-index.

I'd prefer to do it in the design screen. My code is boated enough and this is one of the final steps I need to take.

I've tried highlighting everything and change the tab-index to 0 on everything but it appears that something in my app doesn't have a tab-index which seems to disable that option.

My app contains:

month calendars
buttons
labels
comboboxes
text boxes
sliders
checkboxes
rich text boxes
panels
toolstrip
data grid

I only want the text boxes and combo boxes and buttons to be tab-able.

Comment: Can't you just use the Properties window in the designer?

Answer (score 1):

Well, to set it you could use the Tab Order tool (`View` > `Tab Order`):
[image]

If you need to remove every `TabIndex` property (which is set in the same order that you add the controls to the `Form`), you can go to the `Designer.cs`/`vb` and replace every assignment with nothing, or with a neutral `TabIndex`, like 0. Here's an example using a regular expression to do the replacement:[image]

Comment: OP will probably have to set `TabStop = false` for the controls they don't want to include in tabbing. Of course this can be done via the designer's properties window.

Comment: Hopefully I won't need it to come to this but thank you so much. This is great to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if this isn't what you were looking for, but have you tried using the Tab Order option under View -> Tab Order?

From there you click on where you want the tab order to start and click the next until you are done. This is the simplest way to do it anyway.

Comment: Awesome, I never knew about this. Never saw that setting before. That is INCREDIBLY helpful. Thank you.

Comment: No problem at all. I'm new to Visual Studio myself. So I'm to help!

Comment: For those not being able to find the "Tab Order" under the View menu, here is how to add it back in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15420491/973927